# Value of n for which given expression is a perfect cube

Tags: number-theory

Find a natural number n such that the expression $3^9+3^{12}+3^{15}+3^n$is a perfect cube.
I converted expression to  $3^9(1+3^3+3^6+3^{n-9}).$ Clearly if we prove the expression in bracket to be a perfect cube, we can prove the expression as a whole to be a perfect cube, but I cannot prove the expression in bracket to be a cube further. Please help!

Comment: It seems like $n=14$ is the only solution..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to expand $(1+3^2)^3$ and compare with your expression.

Comment: That's indeed useful if you want to find that solution $n=14$. But I don't see how it brings you closer to proving that this is the only solution...

Comment: Right, but the question didn't ask for ALL solutions.

Comment: Oh I see. I did not read the question carefully. (+1) for your solution then. But nonetheless, it seems an interesting problem to prove that it's the only solution..

Comment: I agree on that.